# Adding Div With IFrame Through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6

I need to `newProductPanelContainer` insie `replaceclass="Replace"` through JS. I'm wondering why this doesn't add anything? I'm adding an iframe to it.

**Where to add**

```
<div class="Replace">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="hi">Hi</div>
  <div class="yes">Wait</div>
</div>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<div class="Replace">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="hi">Hi</div>
  <div class="yes">Wait</div>
  <div class="newProductPanelContainer">
    <iframe id="productPanelIFrame" src="https://test.com" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Iframe div**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
  innerDiv.className = 'newProductPanelContainer';
  innerDiv.innerHTML = `<iframe id="productPanelIFrame" src="https://test.com" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none"></iframe>`;
  innerDiv.style.width = "100%";
    var hello = document.getElementsByClassName("Replace");
hello.appendChild(innerDiv);

</script>
```

Comment: what does this mean? `innerDiv = document.createElement("newProductPanelContainer")`
more information of params: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: @Hao.Le. Updated my question

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you add `innerDiv` to the DOM

Comment: `replaceclass="Replace"` is not the same as `class="Replace"`, so `document.getElementsByClassName("Replace");` will not work

Comment: @JonP. I also tried `document.getElementsByClassName("hello");`. It seems it doesn't work also.

Comment: But why use `replaceclass` as the attribute name? That is a non-standard attribute and will not be found by `getElementsByClassName` because it is not a class attribute.

Comment: Not the part you needed. `<div replaceclass="Replace">` will still **never** work with `getElementsByClassName` , regardless of the value,  as `replaceclass` is **NOT** a class attribute. You want `<div class="Replace">`

Comment: @JonP. ok I removed the replaceclass. Pls check my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. You can iterate over the collection and add the iframe to each element in the collection or select an (probably the first) element and add the iframe to that.

Alternatively use the [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method which returns the first matching element in the DOM. This is what I have done below. Note don't get confused with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which returns a collection.

```js
var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
  innerDiv.className = 'newProductPanelContainer';
  innerDiv.innerHTML = `<p>I'm inserted</p><iframe id="productPanelIFrame" src="https://test.com" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none"></iframe>`;
  innerDiv.style.width = "100%";
    var hello = document.querySelector(".Replace");
hello.appendChild(innerDiv);
```

```html
<div class="Replace">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="hi">Hi</div>
  <div class="yes">Wait</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#1: You can not create an element with specific class name `newProductPanelContainer` with just `document.createElement("newProductPanelContainer")`

you can use the 2nd parameter to do that (the `options`) [refer this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

#2: You can not get the DOM of un-mount element `const productPanelIFrame = document.getElementById("productPanelIFrame");`

the `Iframe.productPanelIFrame` is the children of `div.newProductPanelContainer`. But you can see, its parent has not mounted yet.

Comment: I already updated my question

Comment: Did you add the innerDiv to the DOM? 
And please tell me when you want to add this iframe. Whenever user click a button or something else

Comment: I added in my question the expected output. I updated my question

Comment: the `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection not an Element

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me

```js
const innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
innerDiv.className = "newProductPanelContainer";
innerDiv.style.width = "100%";
const iFR = document.createElement("iframe");
iFR.id = "productPanelIFrame";
iFR.src = "https://test.com";
iFR.width = "100%";
iFR.height = "100%";
iFR.style = "border: none";

const hello = document.getElementsByClassName("Replace");
hello[0].appendChild(innerDiv);
innerDiv.appendChild(iFR);
```

Comment: [here is sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-architecture-1ucvvy?file=/index.html)

Comment: iframe is dynamic. shouldn't be created here

Comment: @Joseph when you want to add the iframe?